# JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python

I have an educational project that perfectly works on web version of Python, but once I tryed to run it on Pycharm I got this error `JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

I tryed all recomendations from stackoverflow they doesn't work, please help. My code `

```
import collections
import json
def read_json():
    with open('sales_log.json') as f:
        sales_json = f.read()
    return sales_json
def evaluate_sales_data(read_json):
    sales_json = read_json
    raw_sales_data = json.loads(sales_json)
    sales_statistics = collections.Counter(raw_sales_data)
    sorted_sales_stat = sales_statistics.most_common()
    return sorted_sales_stat
def main():
    for product, quantity in evaluate_sales_data(read_json()):
        print(product, quantity)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

Comment: The problem is with your data. It's not valid JSON.

Comment: In your `evaluate_sales_data` function, why not just call the argument `sales_json`? That way you don't shadow the name of the `read_json` function, and also you don't have the unnecessary change in variable name

Comment: Thank you, everybody! My bad! You are life savers! I spent about 2 days but the solution was obvious and easy, the Json file on my computer was corrupt (empty)

Comment: @C.Nivs, I just tried what you recommend me to do and it perfectly works, but I can't understand how it is possible the sales_json is the local variable of read_json() function.